# Do the sum of element on the dataset

Tags: mongodb

I have a Dataset:

```
All Entries are done by Single user whose userid is 25.
{ "_id" : 1, "totalAmount" : 150, "userid" : 25 }
{ "_id" : 2, "totalAmount" : 45, "userid" : 25 }
{ "_id" : 3, "totalAmount" : 20, "userid" : 25 }
```

**Now I want to do the Sum of totalAmount i.e 150+45+20 = 215**
My Query is like this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$match: {'userid': 25}},
{$unwind: '$totalAmount'},
{$group: {'_id': '$_id', 'total': {$sum: totalAmount}}}
], function(err, result){
if(err){
console.log(err);
} else {
console.log(result);
}
})
```

Anytell tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to group by the `userid`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group" : {
         "_id" : "$userid", "total": {"$sum" : "$totalAmount"}
     }}
 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$match: {'userid': 25}},
{$group: {'_id': null, 'total': {$sum: "$totalAmount"}}}
], function(err, result){
if(err){
console.log(err);
} else {
console.log(result);
}
})
```